# Request body arrives in different form on Heroku (new line characters)

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework

Weird problem. As an assignment I have to accept only requests with data {'title':'some movie title'}. On local host my code works fine. On Heroku data is always recognized as incorrect.
views.py:

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Data of the post request for debug:")
        print(request.data)
        title = request.data.get('title')
        if not title:  
            return Response({'Error': "Body should be {'title':'The title of the Movie'}"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So for example request with content {'title':'Lord of the rings'} returns invalid body error. Tried with browser (django api site), curl and some web request generator. Locally is fine, on Heroku - invalid request.

So I printed it on Heroku and this is what I got:

```
<QueryDict: {'_content_type': ['application/json'], '_content': ['{\r\n    "title": "snatch"\r\n}']}>
```

Apparently Heroku adds some whitespace characters to received requests. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The problem is not the whitespace. The problem is that the data is within a `_content` key, and the value for that key is a plain string. You need to show how you are sending that data.

Comment: Can you suggest the proper way to send it? I'm using the django api site, sending "Raw data" with media type "Application/JSON" content: {"title": "Snatch"}. I've also used https://apitester.com/ putting {'title':'Snatch'} in Post Data field. Both ways worked when I hosted django locally with runserver.

Comment: Update: sending it with requests.post(url, data={"title":"Snatch"}) works. Same with django site html form, but not with django site raw data form. So the problem is, it works differently locally (all ways work) and Heroku (some ways send improper body).